# How can I create a single react component that receives data from the parent component?

Tags: reactjs

So I started creating this react card component, but I realized there's a big issue in terms of reusability.

Here is the code for my Card and I created a data component to pass in values as well, then it would map the values

```
      import React from 'react';
      import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
      import { CardData } from './CardData';

      function CardItem() {
        return (
          <>
            {CardData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} class='cards__item'>
                  <Link class='cards__item__link' to={item.path}>
                    <figure class='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={item.label}>
                      <img
                        class='cards__item__img'
                        alt='Travel Destination'
                        src={item.src}
                      />
                    </figure>
                    <div class='cards__item__info'>
                      <h5 class='cards__item__text'>{item.text}</h5>
                    </div>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      }

      export default CardItem;
```

Here is the array where my component receives everything

```
      export const CardData = [
        {
          src: 'images/img-2.jpg',
          text: 'Travel ',
          label: 'Luxury',
          path: '/services'
        }
        {
          src: 'images/img-4.jpg',
          text: 'Experience ',
          label: 'Adventure',
          path: '/services'
        }
        {
          src: 'images/img-3.jpg',
          text: 'Swimming',
          label: 'Fun',
          path: '/services'
        }
      ];
```

Now here is where I run into my issues because whenever I add my CardItem component, it will always display the amount of cards in my array, so right now it will always show 3 at a time.

```
           import './Cards.css';
      import CardItem from './CardItem';

      function Cards() {
        return (
          <div className='cards'>
            <h1>Check out these!</h1>
            <div class='cards__container'>
              <div class='cards__wrapper'>
                <ul class='cards__items'>
                  <CardItem />
                  <CardItem/>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

      export default Cards;
```

So the code above will display 6 cards total. So now my issue is if I only want to display 1 card or 2 cards, I would have to go to my array and delete the data until only 1 or 2 objects remain.

However, if I want to add 1 row of 3 cards and then another row on the bottom with 3 cards, but have different images, I can't because my array will end up displaying 6 cards in one row if I add it to my array.

So in short, I need a way to just show one Card and then be able to add any images or properties to that card

Comment: So you want a responsive grid having 3 cards in a row?

Comment: basically you need parent-child component design. meaning, parent component is doing all the business related tasks only and child component is only presentation component, so, data passing from parent to presentation component, so you can reuse all presentation component everywhere.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke with my current CSS it already displays 3 cards in a row, but that's because I have 3 objects in my array. I need a way for the card component to only show one card, then if I needed 3 or 6, I would just write out the component 3 times vs it automatically creating 3 because of my 3 array objects from CardData

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CardData` as your initial data. And in component `CardItem`, you create new local state (eg: `const data = useState(CardData)`). And then, you can override your data by create some actions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using "map" in the wrong component, map should be on the Cards Component, and you send the Data to each CardItem Component as props,

something like this

```
function Cards() {
    return (
        <div className="cards">
            <h1>Check out these!</h1>
            <div class="cards__container">
                <div class="cards__wrapper">
                    <ul class="cards__items">
                        {CardItem.map( (card,i) => (<CardItem card={card} key={i} />)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then modify your CardItem to handle the props.card.

Good luck